# High CPU usage with RTCPeerConnections

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, webrtc

I have the following setup:

[image]

The idea is that **Computer A** captures a single local MediaStream from **Cam 1** using getUserMedia.  Two RTCPeerConnections are then created locally - **R5Outbound** and **R6Outbound**.  Both Computer B and Computer C create their own inbound RTCPeerConnections to capture this stream.

I'm noticing that Computer A - with an i7 CPU - is running hot and occasionally crashes my instance of Chrome (60) with the below setup after hitting 95%+ CPU.

After some reading I'm starting to think that I'm creating too many instances of RTCPeerConnection here; though with multiple streams originating from a single device in some cases, I'm a bit confused about how to properly create and manage my RTCPeerConnections.  My question is - given the above topology and the requirement that all computers need to see all streams (though some computers may not have a stream to share), what RTCPeerConnections should be created?

I should note that mesh is required for now; business constraints have us eager but unable to use an `MCU` or `SFU` architecture.

Some answers to questions:

> How much RAM and disk space is available at Computer A?

16GB / >1TB SSD.

> Why are two outbound streams necessary at Computer A?  What is the purpose of two outbound streams?

Computer A has two cameras attached.  One stream per camera is captured.  Each stream is then shared with each other computer.

> Do you clone the original stream to supply the MediaStream for R5Outbound and R6Outbound?

Both `R5.O` and `R6.O` use the same MediaStream instance (I say that with 80% confidence - need to check my code and post back).

Comment: Can you include a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code to reproduce the issue at Question?

Answer (score 1):

For a mesh network, you've got the right idea. The problem you're experiencing is that transferring MediaStreams across peer connections is an expensive operation. In a mesh network, for every peer connection you make you are uploading your MediaStream and downloading a MediaStream. You can optimize this with an intermediary server that all clients talk to (instead of talking directly to each other). Here is a video for more information on what that looks like: https://vimeo.com/198382135